# Object Reference Not Set whereclause

Tags: c#

I am getting an object reference not set even though I am creating a new instance of a list any ideas as to why.

```
 List<QueryCritera> whereClause = new List<QueryCritera>();
 whereClause=viewConfig.WhereClause;

 foreach (QueryCritera condishion in whereClause)
 {
    string filedname = condishion.fieldName;
    string fieldValue = condishion.Rightvalue;
    string operation = condishion.Operation;
 }
```

Comment: `new List<QueryCritera>();` is useless, since you're reassigning the list to something else immediately after.

Comment: it won't cause an error but it's "condition" not "condishion". Code checking tools will show this up.

Answer (score 1):

Your ViewConfig must be null

```
if(viewConfig != null)
{
   whereClause=viewConfig.WhereClause;
}
```

Comment: Not necessarily. `viewConfig` could be null, `viewConfig.WhereClause` could be null, or the `viewConfig.WhereClause` list could be *not* null but contain null values. We don't know which, because the OP didn't say in which line the error occurred. He'll have to debug his code.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is something of the below:

- the `viewConfig` is `null`
- the `viewConfig.WhereClause` is `null`.
- the `viewConfig.WhereClause` is not `null` but contains `null` values.

In order you find out what of the above is true and act correspondingly, you should debug your code.

> though I am creating a new instance of a list

That's true, you create an **empty** list of  `QueryCritera` objects. However, later you assign to the variable that holds this list, `whereClause`, the `viewConfig.WhereClause`, for which something of the things that mentioned above is true and causes the problem.

Comment: Not necessarily. `viewConfig` could be null, `viewConfig.WhereClause` could be null, or the `viewConfig.WhereClause` list could be *not* null but contain null values. We don't know which, because the OP didn't say in which line the error occurred. He'll have to debug his code.

Comment: @dcastro thank you for you comment ! I will update my answer correspondingly.